# can not accessing repository classes if accessed from a static function in controller c# mvc net EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, static, repository

I working on .net MVC Entity Framework (Code First).
I am not able to get Datacontext in repository classes functions  when i call these functions from a static function in controller
. I am getting the Exception

"An exception of type '`System.NullReferenceException`' occurred in `YYYYYY.Web.dll(Default project dll)` but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

i need to call  static functions since i had to call some functions asynchronously.Like Report generation

This works perfectly fine when called from a non static function in controller.

Thanks in advance
Punnoose

Comment: So much wrong with this, but I'll pick on this line `i need to call a static function since i had to call some functions asynchronously.`, er, what, why?

Comment: i am trying to use hangfire ,Trying to generate some reports asynchronously.